# Why does this SQL stored procedure fail to compare input variable and stored data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

My question relates to a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Azure

I'm creating a login system for a website, using an SQL database. Currently, the user_login procedure is designed to determine if a username and password combination is correct and return a message.

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.user_login
  (@email VARCHAR(128),
  @UserID INT = Null,
  @password VARCHAR(128),
  @sessionID INT = NULL OUTPUT,
  @message VARCHAR(200) = NULL OUTPUT)
AS
  BEGIN

    SELECT @UserID=UserID FROM users WHERE EMAIL=@email AND PASSWORDHASH=PwdEncrypt(@password)
      IF @UserID is NULL SELECT @MESSAGE='Incorrect email or password.'
      IF @message is NULL

      BEGIN

        SELECT @MESSAGE='Login information is correct.'

      END
  END    
GO
```

When a user attempts a login, the message "Incorrect email or password" is always returned, even with correct login information.

Solution: as pointed out by Larnu, the issue was the password was initially processed differently than when it was later processed for comparison. Additionally, the depreciated passwordhash method was being used.

I updated my code to use the HASHBYTES method instead, and this fixed the comparison issues immediately.

Comment: FYI, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you should really be using `HASHBYTES`.

Comment: You can simplify your logic to `SET @MESSAGE = CASE WHEN @UserID is null then 'Incorrect email or password.' ELSE 'Login information is correct.' END;`. If the code is that simple there are 2 possibilities, you are passing the wrong username or password in, **OR** your hashing routine is failing. You can run the SQL manually in SSMS without it being in a SP... and you then debug away... nothing we can do to help though. Also I suggest you could write your question way shorter and way clearer.

Comment: I would include @sessionID OUTPUT in your test query as the second to last parameter - to take out the ambiguity.    Then test with a known pw and hash.

Comment: TBH security-wise you should be hashing the password client side and just pass the hash through to the server to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but I suspect that you inserted your values using a method like `VALUES(PWDENCRYPT('testpassword')` and are falling afoul of a "feature" of `PWDENCRYPT`. Take the below statement:

```sql
DECLARE @password varchar(128) = 'testpassword';
SELECT PWDENCRYPT('testpassword'), PWDENCRYPT(@password);
```

You would be forgiven for thinking that this returns the same value for the 2 expressions, but you would be wrong, this returns the following:

```
0x02002740085548ACA0BEDDEF94EBC9873592F777527768269B4AA5C3E2844D5EE1203EB316342A929D67B9029B1BE8D10015649403778BEDE676954D14FE13E532647FF2A0DB
0x020000EF5FD70A643CF05F88736AA8CBB5B88B72F28DB470D68274DD6C8DEAEC32E731E12CF5B53BF4EC604A08B523CE807B3438517CF3C6AC7515BE8D1C199DD6793101A4B2
```

As you can see, these are *not* the same. If you explicitly cast both values to a `sysname`, the expected input parameter for `PWDENCRYPT`, all works correctly

```sql
DECLARE @password sysname = N'testpassword';
SELECT PWDENCRYPT(CONVERT(sysname,N'testpassword')), PWDENCRYPT(@password);
```

```
0x020095D960131185EB7878A1211AA1A91237AD9106B4C042A84ECFE712BC909368AB8A8D9F7A93F62FB6F1036BD93204994D53E48E8CABA3F7079BBDD7FA961C4A2D397F30C8
0x0200E0A8CB54D88D81498E0579039B2782F0AD06F7D5875B6AC595E4E30102925FC98B5B89107B3BD8B67E63D534578A12BCC906F2E7008AC99C9EF6873C4801EFBFCB6F40CB
```

As, however, is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/pwdencrypt-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `PWDENCRYPT` shouldn't be used any more and you should be using `HASHBYTES`. Use that, and the problem doesn't exist:

```sql
DECLARE @password varchar(128) = 'testpassword';
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','testpassword'), HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@password);
```

```
0x9F735E0DF9A1DDC702BF0A1A7B83033F9F7153A00C29DE82CEDADC9957289B05
0x9F735E0DF9A1DDC702BF0A1A7B83033F9F7153A00C29DE82CEDADC9957289B05
```